# Locally trying to connect to redis running on ec2 instance but getting error despite all traffic inbound

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

The redis is running in the ec2 instance via daemon

```
ps aux | grep redis-server
redis     1182  0.0  0.8  38856  8740 ?        Ssl  21:40   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379

netstat -nlpt | grep 6379
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      1388/redis-server *
```

Temporarily I have set network inbound to all traffic so it is likely not a problem of network security.

```
Type         Protocol Port Range   Source      Description
All traffic  All      All          0.0.0.0/0
```

But when I try to access from the python side:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com', port=6379, db=0)
r.set('foo', 'bar')
r.get('foo')
```

I get the following error:

> ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to
>   ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379. Connection refused.

What may cause such issue despite network inbound is open to all traffic and redis running fine in the ec2 instance ?

Comment: In addition to the redis config, you must also configure the system firewall to allow traffic, as well as the AWS Security zone for your EC2 instance to allow the traffic from your IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `redis` is not listening for connections from outside, instead it listening for local connections only.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Following works for `Ubuntu`. Edit `/etc/redis/redis.conf` and `bind` it to `0.0.0.0`:

```
# bind 127.0.0.1
bind 0.0.0.0
```

and then restart the service:

```
sudo service redis-server restart
```

**WARNING**: Do not allow `0.0.0.0` in your security group. Anyone is allowed. Instead allow only specific IPs or CIDRs.